# How to get rid of useEffect dependency warning?

Tags: react-hooks, use-effect

In my React app, here's a useEffect that is currently working fine:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isProcessing) {
      validate();
    } else {
      if (_.isEmpty(validationErrors)) {
        setIsPosting(true);
      }
    }
  }, [isProcessing]);
```

The issue is that I'm being warned about missing dependencies `validate` and `validationErrors`.  I could add `validate` as a dependency but if I add `validationErrors` it'll mess everything up.

`validationErrors` is a general purpose error collection object that I add to within the `validate` function.  I don't want this useEffect above to be re-run until validation is complete and then `isProcessing` is set to false.

Is there a way to refactor the logic above to get rid of the warning?

Comment: why don't you just comment `validate();` ?? Like `// validate();`

Comment: `validate()` is a completely necessary function call.  Commenting it out would turn off validation.

Comment: Then I dont understand your problem.

Comment: Why dont you decouple the functions?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm wrestling with right now.  The logic I've shared "makes sense" to me.  It's all in once place and is easily readable.  So does it make sense to break it up into smaller & smaller useEffect constructs?  That's what I'm trying to decide.

Comment: Can you share the logic?

Comment: Can you add this on the function? `useEffect(() => { if (isProcessing) { validate(); } else { if (_.isEmpty(validationErrors)) { setIsPosting(true); } } return ()=>{}}, [isProcessing]);`

Comment: @RafaelMora I really appreciate your help but I think you gave me good insight with your decoupling comment earlier.  Thank you so much for that.

Comment: Cool! Let me know if you need more help.